# Use current time and count down to hour and reset to next hour countdown

Tags: javascript, reset, countdown, hour

I am more a php programmer and Java scripting is still new to me. There are allot of counter scripts and questions, but nothing which I can find to do the following. I am using the following script as my base script: [Styled JavaScript Countdown Clock](http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/MwNPVq)

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```css
body{
 text-align: center;
 background: #00ECB9;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

h1{
  color: #396;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 40px 0px 20px;
}

#clockdiv{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 font-weight: 100;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
}

#clockdiv > div{
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #00BF96;
 display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div > span{
 padding: 15px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #00816A;
 display: inline-block;
}

.smalltext{
 padding-top: 5px;
 font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div>
    <span class="days"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to use the current time and let it count down to the next hour, on which it will reset and start again. So on the hour it will be 00:00 (min/sec) and then reset to count down from 59:59 again. Please help!!!

Comment: Please see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). All you need to do is not print the values for days and hours. And `Date.parse(new Date())` is crazy and identical to `Date.now()` It creates a Date, coerces it to a string, then parses it back to a Date and get's it's time value. `Date.now()` gets the current time value directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By subtracting the current minutes * 60 + seconds from 3600 you get the time to the next full hour. Let's add 100 days so the countdown will work for the next 100 days.

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var now = Date.parse(new Date());
var seconds = Math.floor((now / 1000) % 60);
var minutes = Math.floor((now / 1000 / 60) % 60);
var left_to_hour = 60 * 60 * 1000 - (minutes * 60 + seconds) * 1000;
// add 100 days
var deadline = new Date(now + left_to_hour + 100 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```css
body {
 text-align: center;
 background: #00ECB9;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

h1 {
  color: #396;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 40px 0px 20px;
}

#clockdiv{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 font-weight: 100;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
}

#clockdiv > div {
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #00BF96;
 display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div > span {
 padding: 15px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #00816A;
 display: inline-block;
}

.smalltext {
 padding-top: 5px;
 font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Chris G!!!! Youre a GENIOUS!!!!!! WOW!!! Thankyou very much. Like Isaid, I am not a Javascript programmer and you are a Genious. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify the *getTimeRemaining* remaining function so it returns the minutes and seconds to the next full hour, e.g.:

```js
/* Return minutes and seconds to next hour
** @returns {Object} minutes: minutes remaining
**                   seconds: seconds remaining
*/
function getTimeRemaining() {
  var t = Date.now();
  var seconds = (60 - Math.floor(t % 6e4 / 1e3)) % 60;
  var minutes = 60 - Math.ceil(t % 3.6e6 / 6e4) + (seconds? 0:1);
  return {
    'minutes': ('0' + minutes).slice(-2),
    'seconds': ('0' + seconds).slice(-2)      };
}

// Simple show remaining function
function showRemaining() {
  var r = getTimeRemaining();
  document.getElementById('clock').textContent = (r.minutes + ':' + ('0' + r.seconds).slice(-2));
  // Run again just after next full second
  setTimeout(showRemaining, 1020 - (Date.now() % 1000));
}

showRemaining();
```

```html
<span id="clock"></span>
```

Comment: Thankyou Rob and Chris. You guys make the world a better place ;-)